# Vue 3 event naming conventions confusing me

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Inside my parent component, I have a child component:

```html
<upsetting-moment-step
    :this-step-number="1"
    :current-step-number="currentStepNumber"
    @showNextStep="showNextStep"
></upsetting-moment-step>
```

My parent component also has this method:

```
methods: {
    showNextStep() {
        this.currentStepNumber++;
    }
},
```

I call this event from a button in my child component:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @click="showNextStep">Continue</button>
```

Here is the child component method:

```
methods: {
    showNextStep() {
        this.$emit('showNextStep');
    }
},
```

Now this works great, but I'm confused, because it stops working when I use `@show-next-step` instead of `@showNextStep` in the child component tag.

[According to the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#event-names), it SHOULD work, and it is also the recommended way of doing it. However, it simply does not work.

What's funny, is if I change it to snake case, it works if I use `this.$emit('show-next-step');`. However, this is confusing me, because I'm able to pass my props via snake case, and use them in my component via camel case.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your component `upsetting-moment-step` you are using an event with the name  `@showNextStep`, @ - says it is an event.
So, to run some action for the event you need to emit it first (The name must be the same as in the component.
`this.$emit('showNextStep');` to emit the event. Once you emit the event, up to your code, function `showNextStep` will run.

The naming convention is to write using camelCase for JS, and kebab-case for tags and events.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic case transformation of event names *should* work per documentation, as you described. However, there is a known bug ([`@vuejs/vue-next` #2841](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/2841)) in versions 3.0.0 to 3.0.5.

The fix was released in [3.0.6](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#306-2021-02-24), but you should probably update to the latest version ([3.2.7](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#327-2021-09-01) as of today).